# Codeigniter Image Uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I'm a couple weeks into using CodeIgniter for a project (so be gentle) and am having some struggles with getting an image uploaded.  I have the Uploads folder placed in the root folder and have the following code in place.

**For better or worse, I did follow along with a tutorial in an effort to try and learn at the same time as implement this functionality.**

Controller:

```
public function upload(){

        $config['upload_path'] = "/uploads";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload()){

           echo "it worked"; 

           $finfo=$this->upload->data();
           $this->_createThumbnail($finfo['file_name']);
           $data['uploadInfo'] = $finfo;
           $data['thumbnail_name'] = $finfo['raw_name']. '_thumb' .$finfo['file_ext'];
           $this->load->view('project_success');

        } else {echo "it didn't work";}  // This is what I end up getting

    }

    public function _createThumbnail($filename){

        $config['image_library']    = "gd2";      
        $config['source_image']     = "/uploads" .$filename;      
        $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;      
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;      
        $config['width'] = "120";      
        $config['height'] = "80";
        $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
    }
```

}

view:

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('build/upload');?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <span class="number left">3</span>
        <h3>Project Images</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-8 columns">
                    <label for="file">Add Images...</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
                    <input class="button secondary radius wide right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns"></div>
</div>

<br/><br/>
```

These are not in their entirety - I tried to include only the portions of code that were relevant to my issue.  If you'd like the entire view and controller let me know.

Anyone offer any help/advice?  I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Did you check the error_log?  It could be something as simple as the permissions on the upload folder

Comment: I did change the folder permissions in terminal (777)

Comment: make use of the `display_errors()` function in in your `else` condition

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure if I'm using the display_errors() function correctly but it's just returning a white screen.

Comment: duplicate of [file is not uploading in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027765/file-is-not-uploading-in-codeigniter) Same answer: `name="file"` is not what CodeIgniter expects...

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$this->upload->do_upload('file');`

```
$imgUpload1 = array('upload_data1' => $this->upload->data());
```

instead of `$finfo=$this->upload->data();`

then write `var_dump($imgUpload1['upload_data1']);` to see the values.

let me know if it works;

Comment: Check if the image that you are traying to upload is uploaded. If not, maybe the mistake is because you don't have access to the folder. In other words do_upload() function, upload the image to your project and upload->data(), get all data about the image that was uploaded.  Now let's do something, Create a new folder call content in your project, not into application folder. So you will have three folders, application, content and system. Then write this $config['upload_path'] = 'content'; just replace the one that you have for this. try again!!!